# Main AppDelegate

Tags: ios5, delegates, xcode4.2

Sorry for questioning so dummy question, but I swear I used Google before doing it :)

So, the question is - how do I set the main AppDelegate class for my application? I mean, if I don't want to use the one generated by Xcode but to work with my own class for that.

I'm newbie in iOS programming, so probably I misunderstood some part of theory. 
I will highly appreciate any of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine why you would want to reset the app delegate that your template sets up for you, but to it you'd take a .h interface and have it conform to the `<UIApplicationDelegate>` protocol, alloc & init that object (for the sake of arguments, we'd call it `yourNewlyCreatedDelegateInstance`) and then you could set your app delegate to that via `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate: yourNewlyCreatedDelegateInstance]`.

Comment: You know, I also can't imagine such situation. I was too obeyed by book's example so I gave up analyzing what for do we do this. Of course, it's enough just to substitute existing code with my own! Thank you for returning me to the right way :)